# Problema al usar juntas las funciones cell_spec y mutate

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr

Quiero crear una función usando el paquete kableExtra. El objetivo es introducir una tabla o dataframe, y que la función la retorne con algunas celdas en negrita y con un color de texto diferente.

El código de la función es:

```
xKable <- function(tau, var, cond, strCol){

require(kableExtra)
require(dplyr)

kab <- tau %>%
mutate(var = ifelse(paste(var, cond, sep=""), cell_spec(var, "latex", bold = T, color = strCol), var)) %>%
kable("latex", escape = F, booktabs = T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position", "scale_down"))

return(kab)

}
```

Un ejemplo de su uso es:

```
xKable(tau = head(iris), var = "Sepal.Length", cond= ">=5", strCol = "green")
```

Pero no funciona. Sin embargo, si lo hago de forma manual (escrito debajo), entonces sí que funciona:

```
head(iris)%>%
mutate(Sepal.Length = ifelse(Sepal.Length>=5, cell_spec(Sepal.Length, "latex", bold = T, color = "green"), Sepal.Length)) %>%
kable("latex", escape = F, booktabs = T) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position", "scale_down"))
```

Creo que el problema se da al introducir las variables var y cond como un carácter. Cómo podría introducir estas variables, o cambiar el tratamiento que se le da dentro de la función, para que esta las reconozca?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema viene por el lado de la evaluación No estándar (**ENE**) que implementa `dplyr` y el uso dentro de una función de usuario. La **ENE** esta intimamente relacionada con el entorno de evaluación, y el entorno global dónde ejecutas el código, no es el mismo de ese mismo código dentro de una función. Esto suele ser un dolor de cabeza, además de ser un tópico bastante avanzado.

Los problemas puntuales que veo:

- `mutate(var = ...`, aquí es necesario indicar que no queremos que el nombre de la columna sea `var`, sino la cadena a la que apunta `var`, para esto puedes usar el operador `bang bang` o  `!!` como `mutate(!!var := ...`, lo que hace es dejar de considerar `var` como un nombre y entenderlo como la cadena recibida. También es lo mismo hacer uso de `UQ()` (unquote) como `mutate(UQ(var) := ...`
- El otro problema es cuando queremos hacer referencia el nombre de la columna, por ejemplo en `cell_spec(var, ...` esta vez no queremos la cadena sino indicar la columna del `data.frame`, para esto bien puedes usar `cell_spec(!!sym(var), ...`, lo que hace esto es transformar la cadena en un `simbolo` o `nombre` y luego hacer `!!` un "unquoting, para retornar el objeto al cual apunta dicho `nombre`.
- El ultimo de los problemas es la condición del `ifelse`. Es un poco más complejo de resolver, pero nos vamos a apoyar en el paquete `rlang` que nos va a permitir manipular la forma en que evaluamos:

  ```
  cond <- paste(var,cond, sep="")
  ifelse(!!parse_quo(cond, env = caller_env()), .., ..)
  ```

`parse_quo()` interpreta una cadena y retorna un `quosure` o expresión que puede ser evaluada posteriormente en el entorno de la propia función.

Finalmente quedaría algo así:

```
xKable <- function(tau, var, cond, strCol){

    require(rlang)
    require(kableExtra)
    require(dplyr)

    cond <- paste(var,cond, sep="")

    kab <- tau %>%
        mutate(!!var := ifelse(!!parse_quo(cond, env = caller_env()), 
                            cell_spec(!!sym(var), "latex", bold = T, color = "green"),
                            !!sym(var))
        ) %>% 
        kable("latex", escape = F, booktabs = T) %>%
        kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position", "scale_down"))

    return(kab)
}

xKable(tau = head(iris), var = "Sepal.Length", cond = ">=5")


\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lrrrl}
\toprule
Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width & Petal.Length & Petal.Width & Species\\
\midrule
\textcolor{green}{\textbf{5.1}} & 3.5 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.9 & 3.0 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.7 & 3.2 & 1.3 & 0.2 & setosa\\
4.6 & 3.1 & 1.5 & 0.2 & setosa\\
\textcolor{green}{\textbf{5}} & 3.6 & 1.4 & 0.2 & setosa\\
\textcolor{green}{\textbf{5.4}} & 3.9 & 1.7 & 0.4 & setosa\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! La explicación de los 3 casos es muy clara, ahora sí que me funciona.

Answer (score 2):

> Primero posteo la solución y el resultado y luego comento qué se hizo

```
xKable <- function(tau, var, cond, strCol, format="latex"){

    require(kableExtra)
    require(dplyr)

    tau %>%

        mutate(
                !!var := ifelse(eval(parse(text=paste0(get(var),cond))),
                                    cell_spec( get(var),
                                                format,
                                                bold = T,
                                                color = strCol), 
                                    get(var))
                ) %>%

        kable(format, escape = F, booktabs = T) %>%
        kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position", "scale_down"))


}

xKable(tau = head(iris), var = "Sepal.Length",
       cond= ">=5", strCol = "green", format="html")
```

Ejecutando las lineas anteriores se tiene:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde la versión **0.6.0** lanzada en abril del 2017 el paquete `dplyr` permite pasar variables como nombre de columna dinámicamente usando (`!!`) y su asignación se denota por (`:=`), así se tiene que:

```
Sepal.Length =
```

Es equivalente

```
!!"Sepal.Length" :=
```

o como `var <- "Sepal.Length"`

```
!!var :=
```

Por otro lado, como `var` es texto, hacer esto en **R** base

```
 iris$var
```

Producirá `NULL`, y se escapa de ella con `iris[,var]` en `dplyr` su equivalente es:

```
get(var)
```

> Finalmente:

```
paste(var, cond, sep="")
```

Se reemplazó por:

```
eval(parse(text=paste0(get(var),cond)))
```

Porque al ser texto `cond`, tenía que ser evaluada como expresión, usando `eval(parse(text=...`.