# Agregar columnas si cumple con un condicional

Tags: r

Buen día a todos,

Tengo dos data.table (para el ejemplo uso data.frame)

```
df_clientes <- data.frame(cliente = c("X1","X2","X3","X4"),
                          fecha_fact = c("2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-01","2018-01-01"),
                          fecha_pago = c("2018-01-20","2018-01-25","2018-01-07",NA))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y df_gestion

```
df_gestion <- data.frame(cliente = c("X1","X1","X1","X2","X2","X3","X4","X4","X4"), 
                         fecha_accion = c("2018-01-05","2018-01-18","2018-01-23","2018-01-07","2018-01-25",
                                           "2018-01-05","2018-01-05","2018-01-15","2018-01-26"),
                         accion = c("llamada","corte","postcorte","sms","corte","carta","llamada","visita","corte"))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito hacer es ir agregando columnas a df_clientes (Fecha_accion[n] y accion[n]) de la gestión que se le hizo a cada cliente hasta el día del pago, por lo tanto las columnas tienen que irse agregando siempre y cuando se cumpla la condición de ser mayor a fecha_fact y menor a fecha_pago.

he intentado hacerlo de esta forma, pero es lo único que he logrado hasta ahora.

```
f_gestion$fecha_accion <- as.character(df_gestion$fecha_accion)
df_gestion$accion <- as.character(df_gestion$accion)
out <- aggregate(cbind(fecha_accion, accion) ~ cliente, df_gestion, paste)
out[[2]] <- lapply(out[[2]], FUN = function(x) c(x, rep(NA,max(lengths(out[[2]]))-length(x))))
out[[3]] <- lapply(out[[3]], FUN = function(x) c(x, rep(NA,max(lengths(out[[3]]))-length(x))))
x1 <- do.call(rbind, out$fecha_accion)
colnames(x1) <- paste0("Fecha_accion_",1:ncol(x1))
x1 <- cbind(out[c("cliente")], x1)
x2 <- do.call(rbind, out$accion)
colnames(x2) <- paste0("Accion_",1:ncol(x2))
final <- cbind(x1, x2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con esto obtengo una agrupación de df_gestion por cliente y después hago un merge con df_clientes. Pero esto no es viable a mi trabajo porque tengo unos data.table de las de 1 millon de registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para este ejemplo no debería aparecer la fecha_accion_3 ni accion_3 del registro 1 porque esa acción se realizó después de la fecha_pago

Comment: Hola @INDGER puedes proporcionar los `data.frame` como texto que pueda generarse en **R** (`df_clientes<-data.frame(clientes=c("A",...)`), para facilitar su revisión, asimismo sería importante que indiques que has intentado y dónde estás teniendo dificultades, con el fin de que la comunidad pueda ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Hola @HubertRonald, he modificado la pregunta para mayor claridad, espero pueda entenderse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahora tu pregunta está un poco más clara y reproducible. Creo que he dado con una solución a tu problema, aunque he cambiado un poco la estructura del resultado final; Ya te explíco.

Lo primero fue convertir a tipo fecha las variables de los dataframe que compartes.

```
    library(tidyverse) 

    df_clientes <-  df_clientes %>%
      mutate(fecha_fact = as.Date(fecha_fact),
             fecha_pago = as.Date(fecha_pago))

    df_gestion <- df_gestion %>%
      mutate(fecha_accion = as.Date(fecha_accion))
```

Posteriormente, hice un spread del objeto `df_gestion`, para tener cada acción como una columnna y la fecha en la que se relizó la acción como el valor correspondiente a cada una.

```
> (df_gestion <-  spread(df_gestion, key = accion, value = fecha_accion))

  cliente      carta      corte    llamada  postcorte        sms     visita
1      X1       <NA> 2018-01-18 2018-01-05 2018-01-23       <NA>       <NA>
2      X2       <NA> 2018-01-25       <NA>       <NA> 2018-01-07       <NA>
3      X3 2018-01-05       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
4      X4       <NA> 2018-01-26 2018-01-05       <NA>       <NA> 2018-01-15
```

Una vez realizado esto, simplemente hago el `left_join` de ambas bases

```
    > (df_final <- left_join(df_clientes, df_gestion))

  cliente fecha_fact fecha_pago      carta      corte    llamada  postcorte        sms     visita
1      X1 2018-01-01 2018-01-20       <NA> 2018-01-18 2018-01-05 2018-01-23       <NA>       <NA>
2      X2 2018-01-01 2018-01-25       <NA> 2018-01-25       <NA>       <NA> 2018-01-07       <NA>
3      X3 2018-01-01 2018-01-07 2018-01-05       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>
4      X4 2018-01-01       <NA>       <NA> 2018-01-26 2018-01-05       <NA>       <NA> 2018-01-15
```

Entiendo que este resultado satisface tu problema, e incluso vuelve más intuitiva la estructura final del resultado.

Espero esto te funcione.

Comment: Hola @Johan, he modificado la pregunta para mayor claridad

Comment: Hola @JohanRosa vas por la dirección correcta con lo del `full_join` y el `filter`, por eso votaré a favor de vuestra respuesta, sí la amplias un poco más, en tal sentido sólo quería sugerir que por seguridad en el `filter` se emplee `as.Date`. Es importante que se indique también siempre el `paquete` que se emplea, para que google pueda indexar mejor las búsquedas de esa palabra en futuras referencias.

Comment: lo siguiente ya es una recomendación para @INDGER, en este post [Problema al usar juntas las funciones cell_spec y mutate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245629/problema-al-usar-juntas-las-funciones-cell-spec-y-mutate/245824#245824) de acuerdo a lo expuesto hasta el momento, es posible configurar variables dinámicas en `require(dplyr)` esto también te permitiría crear funciones que coadyuven a la personalización de tus reportes, pero sólo es una sugerencia que no hay que perder de vista.

Comment: Hola @JohanRosa vote a favor de vuestra respuesta como señale antes por el `full_join`. Como indica @INDGER está teniendo dificultades con el actual reporte, porque requiere un millón de columnas y algo más... en tal sentido, por eso mencioné que ibas por el camino correcto, no obstante como contestaste primero empleando dicho concepto (aunque ya no está) voté por esa idea.

Comment: Hola @JohanRosa he probado el ```full_join``` que me recomendaste en un inicio, después hago un **Checklist** como el que propone @HubertRonald y seguido si hago el ```spread```, muchas gracias a los dos, ha sido de mucha ayuda, cuando tenga la solución completa la comparto.

Comment: Siempre a la orden @INDGER. El problema que tienes se ve muy interesante, incluso para hacer aplicaciones más profundas de modelos de predicción, pero como es bien sabido en Data Science, la mayor parte del tiempo se le va a uno en la limpieza y organización de los datos.

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien la pregunta, se quiere verificar (una especie de **CheckList**) que pagos estuvieron fuera de fecha, es decir, algo que ya **ocurrió**, esto según veo, implicaría mantener el **"NA"** de las **fecha_pago** porque aún no han sucedido y asumo, se debe llevar por tanto, una especie de control de los mismos en otra instancia.

Por otro lado leo que se comenta lo siguiente:

> *con esto obtengo una agrupación de df_gestion por cliente y después hago un merge con df_clientes. Pero esto no es viable a mi trabajo porque tengo unos data.table de las de 1 millon de registros.*

En tal sentido, el `full_join` que había propuesto inicialmente @JohanRosa soluciona esa restricción del millón de columnas y algo más de columnas.

Por tanto el código con los reportes respectivos quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df_clientes, df_gestion)%>%
    mutate(Check = ifelse(
                            as.Date(fecha_accion) > as.Date(fecha_fact) &
                            as.Date(fecha_accion) < as.Date(fecha_pago) |
                            is.na(fecha_pago),
                            TRUE,FALSE ))

#  cliente fecha_fact fecha_pago fecha_accion    accion Check
#1      X1 2018-01-01 2018-01-20   2018-01-05   llamada  TRUE
#2      X1 2018-01-01 2018-01-20   2018-01-18     corte  TRUE
#3      X1 2018-01-01 2018-01-20   2018-01-23 postcorte FALSE
#4      X2 2018-01-01 2018-01-25   2018-01-07       sms  TRUE
#5      X2 2018-01-01 2018-01-25   2018-01-25     corte FALSE
#6      X3 2018-01-01 2018-01-07   2018-01-05     carta  TRUE
#7      X4 2018-01-01       <NA>   2018-01-05   llamada  TRUE
#8      X4 2018-01-01       <NA>   2018-01-15    visita  TRUE
#9      X4 2018-01-01       <NA>   2018-01-26     corte  TRUE
```

La columna `Check` permite ver el **status de cliente** con respecto a si está **dentro del del intervalo abierto fecha** `]fact, accion[` o aún no hay pago **"NA"** porque como dije, asumo que no es el momento de pagar o quizás el cliente está en mora y requiere seguir sus acciones de control en otra instancia.

Asimismo, a través del operado **AND** (`&`) y **OR** (`|`) se puede ir agregando las condiciones que se necesiten para delimitar el reporte, por tanto, esto viene a ser el **core** de la pregunta y por ende de su respuesta.

De lo anterior con la columna `Check` se puede filtrar los casos que son `falsos` o `verdaderos`.

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df_clientes, df_gestion)%>%
    mutate(Check = ifelse(
                            as.Date(fecha_accion) > as.Date(fecha_fact) &
                            as.Date(fecha_accion) < as.Date(fecha_pago) |
                            is.na(fecha_pago),
                            TRUE,FALSE ))%>%
    filter(!Check)

#  cliente fecha_fact fecha_pago fecha_accion    accion Check
#1      X1 2018-01-01 2018-01-20   2018-01-23 postcorte FALSE
#2      X2 2018-01-01 2018-01-25   2018-01-25     corte FALSE


library(dplyr)
full_join(df_clientes, df_gestion)%>%
    mutate(Check = ifelse(
                            as.Date(fecha_accion) > as.Date(fecha_fact) &
                            as.Date(fecha_accion) < as.Date(fecha_pago) |
                            is.na(fecha_pago),
                            TRUE,FALSE ))%>%
    filter(Check)

#  cliente fecha_fact fecha_pago fecha_accion  accion Check
#1      X1 2018-01-01 2018-01-20   2018-01-05 llamada  TRUE
#2      X1 2018-01-01 2018-01-20   2018-01-18   corte  TRUE
#3      X2 2018-01-01 2018-01-25   2018-01-07     sms  TRUE
#4      X3 2018-01-01 2018-01-07   2018-01-05   carta  TRUE
#5      X4 2018-01-01       <NA>   2018-01-05 llamada  TRUE
#6      X4 2018-01-01       <NA>   2018-01-15  visita  TRUE
#7      X4 2018-01-01       <NA>   2018-01-26   corte  TRUE
```

También no perder de vista que ya el paquete `dplyr` permite definir variables dinámicas facilitando con ello la personalización de funciones y reportes que se requieran. Sobre lo anterior más en este post [Problema al usar juntas las funciones cell_spec y mutate](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245629/problema-al-usar-juntas-las-funciones-cell-spec-y-mutate/245824#245824)

Finalmente lo recomendable sería que las fechas sea del tipo `Date`, para que no sea necesario usar dentro del `ifelse` el `as.Date(...)`